# Parsing through an xml file in Unix

Tags: xml, unix, plist

Trying to parse through a .plist file that has been converted to xml and get back a specific value.

```
The file I'm working with is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-       1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Devices</key>
<dict>
    <key>32467C6D21146CA8</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Connected</key>
        <date>2014-05-17T11:07:47Z</date>
        <key>Device Class</key>
        <string>iPad</string>
        <key>Family ID</key>
        <integer>10010</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version</key>
        <integer>256</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version String</key>
        <string>7.1.1</string>
        <key>ID</key>
        <string>32467C6D21146CA8</string>
        <key>Region Info</key>
        <string>LL/A</string>
        <key>Serial Number</key>
        <string>DKWGD0ETDKPH</string>
        <key>Updater Family ID</key>
        <integer>10010</integer>
        <key>Use Count</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>5C8C4EC2DB1AE41C</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Connected</key>
        <date>2013-05-30T05:54:47Z</date>
        <key>Device Class</key>
        <string>iPhone</string>
        <key>Family ID</key>
        <integer>10016</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version</key>
        <integer>256</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version String</key>
        <string>6.1.3</string>
        <key>ID</key>
        <string>5C8C4EC2DB1AE41C</string>
        <key>IMEI</key>
        <string>990000875537518</string>
        <key>MEID</key>
        <string>99000087553751</string>
        <key>Region Info</key>
        <string>LL/A</string>
        <key>Serial Number</key>
        <string>C39GJGXKDTFC</string>
        <key>Updater Family ID</key>
        <integer>10016</integer>
        <key>Use Count</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>65E875A2AEAB42D4</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Connected</key>
        <date>2014-12-10T02:20:01Z</date>
        <key>Device Class</key>
        <string>iPhone</string>
        <key>Family ID</key>
        <integer>10042</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version</key>
        <integer>256</integer>
        <key>Firmware Version String</key>
        <string>8.1.1</string>
        <key>ID</key>
        <string>65E875A2AEAB42D4</string>
        <key>IMEI</key>
        <string>354408062347668</string>
        <key>MEID</key>
        <string>35440806234766</string>
        <key>Region Info</key>
        <string>LL/A</string>
        <key>Serial Number</key>
        <string>C7KN96QSG5MH</string>
        <key>Updater Family ID</key>
        <integer>10042</integer>
        <key>Use Count</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>com.apple.PreferenceSync.ExcludeAllSyncKeys</key>
<true/>
<key>conn:128:Last Connect</key>
<data>
0Kzt0Q==
</data>
```

My overall goal in the end is to grab the serial number value that has the most recent date and that it is an iPhone.

What I have currently tried is:

```
xmllint com.apple.iPod.plist | grep `date +"%Y"`
```

Which gives me this back:

```
<date>2014-05-17T11:07:47Z</date>
<date>2014-12-10T02:20:01Z</date>
```

Is this on the right track to getting the data that I need? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs four steps and makes use of the `<key>` tags having unique content:

**#1: remove unneeded lines and XML cruft**

```
grep -A1 -E '<key>Connected</key>|<key>Device Class</key>|<key>Serial Number</key>' | grep -v '^--$' | grep -vE '<key>Device Class</key>|<key>Serial Number</key>'
```

will first reduce output to only the needed keys, in the process removing grep's group separator artefacts, then remove the `<key>` lines apart from the first

```
sed 's/^\s*//; s/<.\{3,7\}>//g'
```

will remove the XML tags

**#2: Fold into lines**

```
while read C; do read WHEN ; read WHAT; read SERIAL; echo "$WHEN::$WHAT::$SERIAL"; done
```

This is done via a `while` loop and `read`

It might be nice to show the result so far:

```
2014-05-17T11:07:47Z::iPad::DKWGD0ETDKPH
2013-05-30T05:54:47Z::iPhone::C39GJGXKDTFC
2014-12-10T02:20:01Z::iPhone::C7KN96QSG5MH
```

**#3: Remove non-iPhones, sort and ignore all but last line**

```
grep '::iPhone::'' | sort | tail -n1
```

will do that - this is the real selection step

**#4: Pretty print**

`awk` will get your parameters easily:

```
SERIAL=$(echo "$IPHONE" | awk -F '::' '{ print $3; }'); 
WHEN=$(echo "$IPHONE" | awk -F '::' '{ print $1; }');
```

and finally

```
echo "The last iPhone to connect at $WHEN had serial $SERIAL"
```

So the complete command comes up to a rather unreadable

```
IPHONE=$(cat test.xml | grep -A1 -E '<key>Connected</key>|<key>Device Class</key>|<key>Serial Number</key>' | grep -v '^--$' | grep -vE '<key>Device Class</key>|<key>Serial Number</key' | sed 's/^\s*//; s/<.\{3,7\}>//g' | while read C; do read WHEN ; read WHAT; read SERIAL; echo "$WHEN::$WHAT::$SERIAL"; done | grep '::iPhone::' | sort | tail -n1)
SERIAL=$(echo "$IPHONE" | awk -F '::' '{ print $3; }')
WHEN=$(echo "$IPHONE" | awk -F '::' '{ print $1; }')
echo "The last iPhone to connect at $WHEN had serial $SERIAL"
```

With your sample data this gives **"The last iPhone to connect at 2014-12-10T02:20:01Z had serial C7KN96QSG5MH"**

**EDIT**

This might or might not contain some bashisms - if it fails to deliver, try running it through `bash`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! Am I supposed to put all of this into a shell script for this to run?